# How to design user access system using Keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, amazon-iam

I need help figuring it out how to design a good user access management system using Keycloak.
We have multiple services and we need to implement SSO between them. I'll explain our concerns for just one of them for simplicity's sake.

We have a userType Restaurant, Restaurant user breaks down on several other kinds of access, like owner, employee and cashier. A single user can be owner and employee at the same time, depending on the restaurant.

We tried a lot of different ways, but we are overwhelmed with all the possibilities Keycloak has given to us, I mean scopes, policy, permission, groups, roles, resources. What is the best practice for our use case? Is there a correct approach to this in a way it's easy to build and maintain? Documentation wasn't helpful regarding this problem.

Use case:

**restaurant Best Pizza**

- id: 1
- user: John Doe
- access: Owner
- what he can do: view, edit, delete orders

.

- id: 2
- user: Mark
- access: Employee
- what he can do: view orders

**restaurant Not the Best Pizza**

- id: 2
- user: Mark
- access: Owner
- what he can do: view, edit, delete orders

.

- id: 3
- user: Jane Doe
- access: Employee
- what she can do: view, edit orders